# Kerberos administration client written in Java

Tags: java, kerberos

Is there an implementation of the MIT Kerberos admin protocol in Java which i can use to create an kerberos administration client written in Java?

My application should be able to: 
1.) authenticate with MIT Kerberos Server 
2.) add/delete user/service principals

No kadmin.local calls. JNI Bindings would work, too.

Alternative:
Since kerberos credentials are saved in ldap it is possible to change those information. This might be an easy alternative. But this would mean editing KDCs database itself. This bypasses the kadmin protocol and requires knowledge of how this database is created. This method should not be favored over a kadmin protocol interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Directory Studio, a very nice tool.

Comment: Apache Directory Studio is really great for LDAP. But i am not aware of an option to create kerberos principals within Apache Directory Studio.

Comment: You could maybe write additional bundles for?! It is open source and an Eclipse RCP app.